# Error with Subquery for Select statements

Tags: mysql, select

I tried to excute an inner select query as followed:

```
 SET @rank = 0;
 SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS id,
      (SELECT a.id, COUNT(*) FROM table_A a GROUP BY a.id) AS count
FROM table_e e, table_p p
WHERE id= '100';
```

but I got the error as belowed

“Operand should contain 1 column(s)”

I tested the sub-query on its own and it worked fine. What is wrong with it?

**EDIT**
In fact my count sub query looks like this:

```
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_e e, table_p p a GROUP BY p.id) AS count
```

I´m trying to count how many items in table_e exist in table_p.

Comment: Don't you want to join `table_e` on `table_p` at all?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is following part of your query, which selects two columns for one alias:

```
(SELECT a.id, COUNT(*) FROM table_A a GROUP BY a.id) AS count
```

Bases to the name of the alias, selecting a.id is probably not needed.